# How to use CORS to access Flipkart API?

Tags: jquery, ajax, cors

I'm trying to access below URL using jQuery ajax call..

Ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url: 'https://affiliate-api.flipkart.net/affiliate/report/orders/detail/xml?startDate=2015-05-01&amp;endDate=2015-05-30&amp;status=Pending&amp;offset=0',
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Fk-Affiliate-Id", "XXXXXX");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Fk-Affiliate-Token", "YYYYYYYYYYYYY");
    },
    success: function(data){
        $('#response').html(data);
    }
});
```

I'm getting below error..

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://affiliate-api.flipkart.net/affiliate/report/orders/detail/xml?startDate=2015-05-01&endDate=2015-05-30&status=Pending&offset=0. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).
>
> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://affiliate-api.flipkart.net/affiliate/report/orders/detail/xml?startDate=2015-05-01&endDate=2015-05-30&status=Pending&offset=0. (Reason: CORS request failed).

Comment: This worked for me: https://frontendguruji.com/blog/flipkart-affiliate-api-cross-origin-error/

Answer (score -2):

you need use jsonp inorder to fix it

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "[]",
        jsonp: 'callbackme',
        dataType: "jsonp",
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: false
        },
        headers: {
             'Fk-Affiliate-Id': 'xxxx',
          'Fk-Affiliate-Token': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        success: function(data) {
            for (i = 0; i < data.allOffersList.length; i++)
                alert(data.allOffersList[i].title);
        },
    }); //end ajax
```